# how to view data based on clicked id

Tags: php, database

im trying to view data based on clicked id, this is my button to catch the clicked id

```
<a href="viewfull.php?id=<?php echo $result->id?>"class="btn btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></i> Edit </a>
```

and this is my viewfull.php code

```
<?php
include 'koneksi/koneksi.php';
$ID = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM  t_koperasi WHERE id_koperasi = '$ID'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
include 'views/v_data.php';
```

and this is the code to echo the data

```
<?php
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {?>
<h1>Nama Koperasi : <?php echo $result->nama_koperasi ?></h1>
```

the issue is when i click the view button the data isnt there it was just white blank

Comment: good. You forgot to mention the issue...

Comment: oh than you for reminding

Comment: @LuthfiMusafa for this u need to use JQuery or ajax call thank you